# start mysqld unable to updating PID

Tags: mysql, unix, terminal, pid

So I recently tried starting mysqld via terminal and now i get an `ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/computer-name.local.pid)`. I tried to kill the process, uninstall and reinstall MYSQL, reset OSX, and even the "kill `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/localhost.pid`" cmd.

I also tried getting and looking in the data file (`/usr/local/mysql/data/`) as the super user but I still can not get in. Are there certain things I need to understand before I can open it if it even can be opened?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:_mysql /usr/local/var/mysql
```

This is most likely a permission issue. Check for err file and see whether the missing file is present here

`/usr/local/var/mysql/*.err`

If you are on MacOS,

```
cd /usr/local/var/mysql 
sudo rm *.err && sudo rm *.pid 
sudo reboot
sudo mysql.server start
```

Comment: @john did you try this?